# Updating MSSQL table with PHP + sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to do the simplest thing...

I have a form with 2 fields. I want to enter data in those fields and have them write that data to my db (mssql using sqlsrv driver).

Connecting to the db isn't a problem. Here's my form processor (only set up to update quantity (qnty) at the moment):

```
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$partno = $_POST["partno"];
$qnty = $_POST["qnty"];

$sql = 'UPDATE WestDevDB SET LocationQty = $_POST["qnty"]';

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
```

All I get is the error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in filepath\file.php on line 8
>   Array

and nothing writes.

I've tried changeing `$_POST["qnty"]` to `$_POST["qnty"][0]` thinking that would solve the issue, but it makes no difference.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic PHP Syntax 101: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables. That means your query definition:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE WestDevDB SET LocationQty = $_POST["qnty"]';
```

is sending the literal characters `$`, `_`, `P` etc... as the value to compare `LocationQty` against. That also means that your query is causing a syntax error, because `$_ etc...` is not a valid field name, in pretty much any database under the sun.

And even if `'`-quoted strings DID interpolate variables:

a) you'd be wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) anyways.
b) Array keys cannot be quoted inside strings, unless you using the `{}` syntax:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ... = {$_POST['qnty']};"
or
$sql = "UPDATE ... = " . $_POST['qnty'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) to avoid sql injection and errors on string concatenations.

```
$qnty = $_POST["qnty"];
//sanitize $qnty ( !is_null, is_numeric, ... )
$sql = "UPDATE WestDevDB SET LocationQty = ( ?)";
$params = array( $qnty );

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

More [sqlsrv_query update samples at Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above are answering the question. You have no WHERE statement. You are attempting to set LocationQty for every row in your database table. That's why it's not working

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your answer.